# Customize Onboard-SDK of a DJI drone

Tags: c++, dji-sdk

Starting from the [DJI website](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/introduction/homepage.html) I went on the *Quick start* section to understand how it is possible to customize and control the movements of the drone writing code.
I ended up in the [Github repository](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK) where the company provide a sample of the OSDK to controle the drone. I noticed that in the *sample/core/src* folder are provided some files containing classes and functions related to the drone's operation management.

My question, considering that I am a newby in this field, is: Where should I start writing code to customize the drone operations, using the classes and functions provided? Where is or what is the *main* file from which all the logical flow starts?

Currently, I am just trying to understand what is inside the repository to try understand where to start put my hands on